# iOS:When I setFrame to tableView for change the height,it did not work

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

[image: This pic is my problem]

---

It did not work.

```
[self.tableView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 600)];
```

I set the frame for a highter height,but id does not work.

Comment: it is working you need to give [self.tableView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 64, 320, 600)]; then you see the change

Comment: Are you using autolayout ?

Comment: @Spynet My tableView was added on a backView which is added on self.view, so there is no relationship with '64'.

Comment: My tableView did not use autolayout

Comment: did you tried ? or else post with entire code how your creating the table view and back view and self.view

Comment: [self.tableView setFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)]; then final try add like that

Comment: Yes, i tried. I will post my code in detail, thx ur suggestion.

Comment: Did U tried that one  
[self.tableView setFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

Comment: is table view is inside any subview? if yes ,you should increase height of the  subview too.

Comment: @Spynet  Hi,handsome boy, sorry for your waiting, I have found the reason, that is: the tableView is added on 1th controller, then the controller use auto layout,thought my tableView does not use autolayout, and the 1th controller is added on 2th controller which is the picture show.  I resolved the problem by :NSArray *constrans = self.tableView.constraints;
        for (NSLayoutConstraint *constraint in constrans) {
            
            if (constraint.firstAttribute == NSLayoutAttributeHeight) {
                constraint.constant = 377;
            }
            
        }

Comment: Can you post the frame for self view and the back view which you have mentioned?

Comment: @廖马儿 Thank man , i happy to help you . One Kind advice single line of code will not resolve your problem and you need elaborate with code , While asking the Question man Keep coding....

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
  - (void) viewDidLayoutSubviews
   {
        [self.tableView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 600)];
   }
```

Comment: It looks like not useful foe me.Thx anyway.

Comment: @Spynet   Hi,handsome boy, sorry for your waiting so much time, I have found the reason, that is: the tableView is added on 1th controller, then the controller use auto layout,thought my tableView does not use autolayout, and the 1th controller is added on 2th controller which is the picture show.  I resolved the problem by :
I added constrains to my tableView.At the code, i change the constraint

Comment: NSArray *constrans = self.tableView.constraints;
        for (NSLayoutConstraint *constraint in constrans) {
            
            if (constraint.firstAttribute == NSLayoutAttributeHeight) {
                constraint.constant = 377;
            }
        }
 Thx all of you for attention the issue sincerely.